# Nodejs App always crashes when deploying on Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, express, web-deployment

I have a simple Nodejs app that works fine locally but Heroku doesn't manage to run it correctly :

```
Process exited with status 130 
2015-09-19T15:56:22.872647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-brushl.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Despite the build succeeded that Heroku displays

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── body-parser@1.14.0
remote:        ├── express@4.13.3
remote:        ├── jade@1.11.0
remote:        ├── mongoose@4.1.7
remote:        ├── morgan@1.6.1
remote:        └── stylus@0.52.4`
```

Nodejs version used is 4.0.0.

What is making me "crazy" is that when I try to run the app with `heroku run node server.js` everything works fine.

I've already searched on internet for a long time and I realized that almost all crashes (`H10`) of first deploys of Nodejs apps on Heroku generally come from a bad port use, but in my case I'm using a good one 
`var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);`

Any help would be really appreciated because I'm getting a headache with this `H10` error (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out !

There were an extra whitespace between "web" and the ":" in my Procfile :

```
web : node server.js
```

So by deleting it (`web: node server.js`) it worked fine !